# MongoDB regular expression not working as expected

Tags: regex, mongodb

```
db.col.find({_id: {term: "garcia"}})
```

finds the document with term = "garcia". However,

```
db.col.find({_id: {term: /garcia/}})
```

doesn't find anything. What's the reason?

Document:

```
{ "_id" : { "term" : "garcia" }, "count" : 43512, "count_users" : 15388 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query using `{_id: {term: /garcia/}}` is asking for an exact match on `_id` itself, not just the `term` field within it.  So it's trying to find a doc where `_id` is an object with a single `term` field with a *value* of that regular expression.

Use dot notation to match the regular expression against just the `term` field:

```
db.col.find({'_id.term': /garcia/})
```